# CalloutException: you have uncommitted work pending - without DML?

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, asynchronous

I want to test a Queueable class that makes callouts to an external system. I'm baffled because I keep getting uncommitted work pending exception.

My execute method queries custom metadata, constructs a JSON based on provided objects and makes a callout. It does not do any DML. As I can see in the logs, at the end of execution after the exception has been thrown, the test setup uses some DML statements but my Queueable class doesn't even use SOQL. Why am I getting a CalloutException? My API version is 47 but it also fails for later versions.

After changing code and further digging I see I get the exception because of the setup code. In the test setup I create an Opportunity and a Quote. The quote insertion triggers updates on opportunity (no callouts). When I just create the opportunity and I comment out the lines from quote creation onwards the test is passing. When I create a quote and keep the below objects commented out it fails.

I even moved custom metadata retrieval to the synchronous part of the test. I'm not doing any DML, SOQL in the async. code. The test passes when I comment out the setup method from Quote creation onwards but fails if the quote is inserted in setup. ***Why is the setup affecting my asynchronous callout test?***

```apex
@isTest
public with sharing class MyQueueableTest{

    @TestSetup (simplified code)
    static void createTestRecords(){
        //Test.startTest();
        System.runAs([Select id from User where Id=:userInfo.getUserId()][0]){
            insert new Account();
            insert new Opportunity();
            insert new Quote();
            insert new Contract();
            insert new Case();
        }
        //Test.stopTest();
    }
        
    @isTest   
    static void my_caloutTest(){

            MyQueueable m = new MyQueueable([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);
            Test.startTest();
                    MyQueueableMock mock = new MyQueueableMock(201);
                    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class,mock);
                    System.enqueueJob(m);
            Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(true, mock.isCalled);
    }
}
public with sharing class MyQueueable Implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts{

    List<SObject> records;
    Map<String, String> integrationConfig;

    public MyQueueable(List<SObject> records){
         this.records = records;
         integrationConfig = getCustomMetadataForCalloutEndpoint();
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context){
        
        for(Sobject cse : records){
        
            HttpRequest request = prepareRequest(integrationConfig);
            request.setBody(cse.Id);
            
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse  response = http.send(request);
        }
    }

    public HttpRequest  prepareRequest(Map<String, String> configMap){
        return new HttpRequest();
    }
}
```

```
 19:16:09.929 (7929233319)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
 19:16:09.929 (7929233319)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)| 
  Number of SOQL queries: 38 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 224 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 17 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 17 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 1471 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

19:16:09.929 (7929233319)|TESTING_LIMITS
19:16:09.929 (7929233319)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 1 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In the test class are u making  a DML just before calling the method that does the callout ?

And in test class we follow two practices have you executed them ?

1. Callouts should have mock class

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

2. Async calls are enclosed inside Test.startTest and Test.stoptTest which executes them in a synchronous manner for the test class(Both Batch and callouts are async in nature)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm

The 2nd point should resolve your problem , if the issue still persists feel free to share  the Test code snippet, it will be helpful to understand and resolve your problem